# Issue with worker service project (Can´t start the service. System error 193)

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2022, worker, .net-7.0

I created a Worker Service project in visual studio 2022 (followed a tutorial on youtube) and i published it to a folder. The objective is to get it to run on the background like windows services.

After publishing it, i ran this command:
sc create WorkerService11 binpath= "C:\Users\João Silva\source\repos\C# academy course\Math Game - maui\WorkerService11\WorkerService11\bin\Debug\net7.0\PublishWorkerService11.exe" start="demand"
To basically create the service (that is the path to where the executable file is). Then, i went to services and tried to start the service, but i got this and error that said i got "System Error193" and that its not a valid win32 aplication. (My windows is 64bits).
Also i tried the command "net start WorkerService11" to basically start the service trough the console, but i got the same error...

If i just click on the executable, it starts and runs just fine. So, i am not sure why i cant get it to run on the "background".

I was expecting to start the service and to run the aplication in the background. But when i try to start it i get the error i mentioned above.

I tried some other console commands, checking the path directory and changing to different locations, also tried publishing the app in a few different ways (trough visual studio 2022 - the target framework is .net7 btw). But none fixed that error. Im simply not able to start the service after i publish the app and create the service.